# Add an aggregation to a django query set

Tags: mysql, django, aggregate-functions, aggregation

Hopefully easy question.  I have a query set of actions and each action has a time_estimate.  I want to get the average time_estimate across all of the actions in the queryset such that this returns the average:

```
{{ actions.avg_time_estimate }}
```

I tried

```
actions.avg_time_estimate = actions.aggregate(Avg('time_estimate'))
```

but this is assigning a dictionary to actions.avg_time_estimate, meaning I get my average like this:

```
{{ actions.avg_time_estimate.effort__avg }}
```

What is the correct way to pull the average into the queryset?  I also want to retain the actual list of actions in the query.

Comment: Could this be done by adding in the Aggregate as an extra to the QuerySet? (see [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `actions = actions.aggregate(avg_time_estimate=Avg('time_estimate'))`

Comment: This gives me the average, but then I lose the query results (question edited above)

Comment: These are two separate queries at the DB level anyway if you want to the average for everything in the query set. Alternatively since you want all the results, you could just calculate the average once you get the results to avoid a second query.